# Sidebar not displaying correctly in responsive mode

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, responsive-design, sidebar

I have a Wordpress website (footballrepublik.com) that has the Point responsive theme, however, I'm having a few issues with the responsive mode when in landscape mode and also when it is viewed on an iPad.

In the right-hand sidebar, when viewed in landscape on Android (Kindle Fire HDX) the social media buttons, a couple of widgets, and a NewsNow logo are not displaying properly. They go beyond the width of the sidebar, which is obviously annoying.

I have the same issue on the iPad, however, this is always present (in landscape and portrait mode).

I have very basic CSS/html knowledge, and have built my site by trial and error, but I would like to rectify the above problem.

Is there any code that can be added to the sidebar widgets to make them display properly? I have looked everywhere, but have had no joy.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you need a lot of css tweaking to do. Better hire someone who can look into your Wordpress css to fix this issue for you. BTW nice site :)

Comment: And the layout problems are not because of the device. It is because of the screen sizes. You can replicate the same problem in your pc or mac, by resizing browser window. Your css or the 3rd party widget css is not good enough to handle these screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks Wishchaser, I though as much, unfortunately! I'm a writer not a coder, so I'll have to see if I can get someone who actually understands CSS rather than me just tweaking and checking every 10 seconds...